# How to test if one of many values

Tags: php, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a way to compress an if statement with multiple 'OR' conditions?

For example, would it be possible to compress something like:

```
if ($foo == ('10') || $foo == ('30') || $foo == ('57') || $foo == ('59'))
{
// Do This
}
```

So that is was something like this:

```
if ($foo == (array('10','30','57','59')))
{
// Do This
}
```

The above doesn't seem to work, am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: You can also use short array syntax: `if (in_array($foo, [1,2,3,4])) { ... }`

Comment: Why mark down my question? What is the purpose of Stack Overflow?

Comment: +1. I think your question would be better for SO if its title more clearly explained what you're trying to do (also, doesn't need PHP in the title). How about `How to test if one of many values` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close!  Use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) to test if a value is in an array.

```
if ( in_array($foo, array('10','30','57','59')) )
{
    // Do This
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) - you have the right idea but just the incorrect syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in the in_array function.

https://www.php.net/in_array

```
if (in_array($foo,array('10','30','57','59'))
{
    // Do This
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the in_array function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php